# Using Ajax with multiple select

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a multiple select form that I am now trying to use with AJAX. The drop down is supposed to act as a filter for images.

Index.php

```
<script>
function filterResults(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","filter_ajax.php?filter="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<form action="" class="css_form" id="picture_filter" name="picture_filter">
    <select onchange="filterResults(this.value)" multiple="multiple" name="filter[]" id="filter">
     <option value="filter_name_1">Filter name 1</option>
     <option value="filter_name_2">Filter name 2</option>
     <option value="filter_name_3">Filter name 3</option>
     <option value="filter_name_4">Filter name 4</option>
</select>
<div id="divResults"></div>
```

and filter_ajax.php

```
<?php

include ("connect.php");

    $filter = $_GET["filter"];
    $filterIn = implode("','",$filter);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM edt_images
                                WHERE category1 IN ('$filterIn')
                                OR category2 IN ('$filterIn')
                                OR category3 IN ('$filterIn')
                                OR category4 IN ('$filterIn')
                                OR category5 IN ('$filterIn')
                                OR category6 IN ('$filterIn')")
            or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<img src='files/small/thumb0_".$row['item_name'].".".$row['file_extension']."' border='0'/>"; 
        }

?>
```

In my database each image has six entries which correspond to the categories, and are filled with subcategories. Thus whats supposed to happen is that when an item is selected from the "filter drop-down" it should query each six columns for that information. However I am receiving the following error and output:

implode(): Invalid arguments passed in ... Line 6.

For testing I have five entries. 3 which have all information filled in for the six categories entries, and two which were left blank.

The two that are left blank are always returned with the error above.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the value you're sending to the script isn't an array, hence you can't use implode on it. The fact that the HTML <select> element has an array type doesn't matter, since that's not what you're sending to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `<select>`:

```
<select onchange="filterResults(this)" multiple="multiple" name="filter[]" id="filter">
```

and try this (note: you don't need to implode array with "," on server-side - that is already done with JS in the example):

```
function filterResults(sel)
{
    var selectedOptions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i++) {
        if (sel.options[i].selected) {
            selectedOptions.push("'" + sel.options[i].value + "'");
        }
    }
    if (selectedOptions.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    str = selectedOptions.join(",");
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else  {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?filter="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

UPD:
Modify your SQL also:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM edt_images
                                WHERE category1 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR category2 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR category3 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR category4 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR category5 IN ($filterIn)
                                OR category6 IN ($filterIn)");
```

Comment: Right on! Thanks Chvanikoff this almost works...Only problem I'm having now is that if two or more items are selected then no results are displayed.

Comment: did you modify address from test.php to yours filter_ajax.php? I forgot to modify it after the code check.

Comment: I did yep, it will work if only one item is selected, but not if two or more are

Comment: Check out updated answer. I've also fixed JS to clean up if no options were selected.

Comment: Thanks again, I was just trying to fix that, didn't want to ask for more thank you had already done. So thank a lot, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're sending to your PHP script, is not an array. So you cannot use `implode()` on it and `implode()` is returning an error. Run this:

```
var_dump($filter);
```

Then you can decide how to modify your code based on the result.

Comment: OK from using this I notice not only I am not sending an array I can only make one call, so if the user selects a second subcategory, nothing would happen. I'll Google how to pass an array using AJAX.

Comment: @Owen try encoding the array in json